# How do users check virtual mailboxs in Postfix?

Tags: postfix

I have configured a new instance of postfix to use a virtual domain with a virtual mailbox. This means that my email recipients don't each have logins to the mail server. This is intended because I don't want to have to make a login for every mailbox owner since I don't want them logging into the mail server. But now I wonder. How are these people supposed to check their mail? I am still deciding whether to use courrier or dovecot as a POP/IMAP solution. But before getting that going they don't have associated credentials to retrieve emails with. What am I missing here? Is there supposed to be another mechanism to push messages from /var/mail to the users inbox wherever it may be hosted at?

Comment: /var/mail is their inbox your hosting it.

Answer (score 1):

When you select Courier or Dovecot, you will configure it for the virtual users you have already set up. But you still have to pick one!